# error failed to compile not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

Am developing a login form that will accept values from the following API: https://api.myjson.com/bins/11unjr

...currently, the password field is blank, so any password is accepted. I get the error: Failed to compile  '**userName' is not defined  no-undef; 'pwd' is not defined no-undef**.

the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Login.css';

class Login extends Component {  

    state = { data: [] }

    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/5432', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiR3JlZyIsInVuaXF1ZV9uYW1lIjoiZ2dyYWZmIiwibmJmIjoxNTI0ODM5Nzc1LCJleHAiOjE1MjQ5MjYxNzV9.xhvdfaWkLVZ_HLwYQuPet_2vlxNF7AoYgX-XRufiOj0'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: 'userName',
                password: 'pwd',
            })
        }

        ) /*end fetch */
        .then(results => results.json()) 
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }))   
      }

    //render component
    render() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">

                <div className="loginContainer">
                    <h2>Member Login</h2>
                    <form>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label for="username">User Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{userName}" placeholder="Enter User Name" name="userName" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group"> 
                            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="{pwd}" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" onClick="getInfo" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                   </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div> 

        );
      }

//function
        getInfo() {
            var username = document.getElementById('{userName}').value
            var password = document.getElementById('{pwd}').value

            if(username == {userName} && password == {pwd}) {
               window.location.href="MemberInfo.jsx";
                return
            }

        } 
//end function
}

export default Login
```

could I get some help with this please?

Comment: Is your goal, simply to cache user input and use it to make an API call. why are you manually querying the DOM?  Perhaps you should look into [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and attach an event handler to the `onSubmit` event of the form node in order to trigger your API call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant mix vanillaJS getElementById with react .... at first you will get very weird behaviour as React do heavy DOM manipulation inside JSDom not real dom, (so in cycles you can have this element not in DOM) and secondly you have weird ID naming for dom ID `{userName}` this would confuse even jQuery not React.

You have to turn your inputs to controlled inputs https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html where you will bind it's `onChange` listener and pass value from `event` in Docs there is nice example how to achieve that.